# How do I sort a VARCHAR column in PostgreSQL that contains asterisks

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

```
select folder_name  -- varchar
from ags_secured_endpoint_definition;
```

returns:

```
Utilities
Utilities
UtilityServices
*** ROOT ***
Midstream
EP
EP
EP
EP
EP
EP
Midstream
Culture
Culture
Culture
Culture
Culture
Culture
CustomUtilities
Basin
Basin
EP
EP
EP
```

Sorted I get an unexpected result ("*** ROOT ***"):

```
select folder_name 
from ags_secured_endpoint_definition
ORDER BY folder_name;
```

returns:

```
Basin
Basin
Culture
Culture
Culture
Culture
Culture
Culture
CustomUtilities
EP
EP
EP
EP
EP
EP
EP
EP
EP
Midstream
Midstream
*** ROOT ***
Utilities
Utilities
UtilityServices
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your collation, which you can see with

```
SHOW lc_collate;
```

Obviously your collation ignores spaces and asterisks when sorting, so `*** ROOT ***` is sorted like `ROOT`.

You can choose a different collation if you don't like that, for example binary:

```
SELECT folder_name 
FROM ags_secured_endpoint_definition
ORDER BY folder_name COLLATE "C";
```

Comment: Thank you - your response answered my question!